# Client side kerberos authentication confluent-kafka python

Tags: kerberos, confluent-platform

I have kafka running on a cloudera cluster, and have a kerberos user(username/password) to authenticate with. I am trying to authenticate a confluent-kafka producer/consumer, but I am having trouble doing so. I am able to stand up kafka locally and produce/consume without any issues, and was able to hit the kafka instance on the cluster before kerberos was added. I was able to find some documentation around setting Kerberos up for the cluster(this is already done), but not how to authenticate from client side with username/pass.

Here is some info on versions I am using:

Kafka version: 0.11.0-kafka3.0.0
confluent-kafka version: confluent-kafka (0.11.0)
librdkafka version: 0.11.3

Here is my simple Producer conf without authentication:

```
Producer({'bootstrap.servers': broker_url}, {'api.version.request': True})
```

From some googling I've tried things like this(and some slight modifications):

```
p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': broker_url}, {'api.version.request': True}, {"security.protocol", "PLAINTEXT"}, {'sasl.username': 'username'}, {'sasl.password': 'password'})
```

I get this error message(repeatedly in rapid succession, cluster_broker_name removed for security purposes)

%5|1521746707.533|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka_url:9092/bootstrap]: kafkaPurl:9092/bootstrap: Connection closed
%3|1521746707.533|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka_url:9092/bootstrap]: kafka_url:9092/bootstrap: Connection closed
%3|1521746708.538|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka_url:9092/bootstrap]: kafka_url:9092/bootstrap: Receive failed: Disconnected
%3|1521746708.538|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka_url:9092/bootstrap]: kafka_url: Receive failed: Disconnected
%3|1521746708.538|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka_url:9092/bootstrap]: 1/1 brokers are down

I am trying to figure out what to add to configuration to authenticate(with username and pass). If appending to the configuration is not the way to do this, then I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Basically, i want the confluent-kafka equivalent of this in kafka-python:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='example.com:9095', security_protocol="SASL_PLAINTEXT", sasl_mechanism='PLAIN', sasl_plain_username='username', sasl_plain_password='password')
```

I am new to confluent-kafka (and not too familiar with security in general) so I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question.. Thanks in advance, I would appreciate any and all help!

Comment: https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/wiki/Using-SASL-with-librdkafka

Comment: Thank you for the response! I saw this link when browsing previous confluent-kafka issues on your github page. Is there anything i need to set besides security_protocol, username, and password? The Kafka broker running on the cluster i references already has SASL configured. I am merely trying to authenticate from a client.

Comment: The required config properties for a kerberos client are outlined on that wiki page, `sasl.kerberos.keytab` and `sasl.kerberos.principal` in particular.

Comment: So my original approach was to try with these and wasn't able to get it to work. Turns out my issue was not having the cyrus-sasl-gssapi package installed. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave,

Are you 100% sure your broker's listeners are configured to use Kerberos?(SASL mechanism GSSAPI)?

I ask because the example you provided shows the use of the PLAIN mechanism.

`security_protocol="SASL_PLAINTEXT", sasl_mechanism='PLAIN'`

This may also explain why your Java clients are able to login without the use of a keytab. Alternatively they may have the JAAS logon module configured to use the local credential cache instead.

If the broker's listeners are in fact configured to use the PLAIN SASL mechanism then you need to pass sasl.mechanism="PLAIN" in addition to security.protocol = "PLAINTEXT", sasl.username = "username" and sasl.password = password.

Do note that he broker will need to be configured to accept this username and password as well. I have linked our docs below which include instructions on how you would configure your broker.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl.html#plain

Comment: Seems that you are trying to edit your post from another account - try to avoid doing this, as this takes away editors time. If you want to use another account, try reposting your answer and remove the original. If you cannot remove the original post (if you cannot get access to that account), flag post for moderator attention and try explaining the situation.

Comment: I apologize for that; I keep two browsers open, one for work one  for personal and accidentally switched between the two.

Comment: I am using SASL_PLAINTEXT, and I was able to resolve the issue. I'm new to alot of this and did not fully understand at first but i was able to learn and resolve the issue. Thanks for your reply!